# Proof Directional Derivative Exists at (0,0)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Before I post this I would just like to state that I know that there is a very similar question with a very similar function but I've gone through the answer and it doesn't really help me.

Consider a function:

$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^4+y^4} $ if $x \not = 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Show that the directional derivative exists in any direction at the point (0,0)

We've also been given the definition of directional derivative in direction $e = (e_1, e_2)$ as:

$ \frac{d f(a,b)}{d e}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(a + he_1, b + he_2) - f(a,b)}{h}$

Now using this definition I get to the solution as follows:

$ \frac{df(0,0)}{de} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{he_1he_2}{(he_1)^4 + (he_2)^4}}{h}$

$ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{h^2e_1e_2}{h^4(e_1^4 + e_2^4)}}{h}$

$ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2e_1e_2}{h^5(e_1^4 + e_2^4)}$

$ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e_1e_2}{h^3(e_1^4 + e_2^4)} $

but clearly this limit diverges??? So the limit does not exist? Did I make a stupid algebraic mistake somewhere? Or am I missing something entirely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the subset $x = y$,
$$f(t,t) = \frac{t^2}{2t^4}  = \frac1{2t^2}$$
is unbounded near $(0,0)$, i.e. $f$ is discontinuous on the subset $x = y$ and the corresponding directional derivative can't exist.

But the *partial* derivatives exists because on the axes $f$ is zero.

Comment: Okay...but the directional derivatives do not exist?? I understand that it is discontinuous (that was actually the first part of this problem) but, what you're saying is that the directional derivative doesn't exist? So there's some sort of typo in the problem?

Comment: @gloveman998, a directional derivative (in $(0,0)$) is the derivative at $t = 0$ of the composite function $t\mapsto f(te)$. If it exists,  $f$ is bounded in the subset $\{te\,|\,t\text{ small}\}$. Bottom line: you can check that the only directional derivatives that exists in this case are the partial derivatives ($e = (1,0),(0,1)$).

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was thinking with @Martin-Blas Perez Pinillas answer. Okay thank you for your explicitness.